# Privileges for jenkins at apache's folder

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, group, privileges, jenkins

I'm having issue similar to this:
[How to copy files as Jenkins "post build" action if i don't have privileges to destination directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128324/how-to-copy-files-as-jenkins-post-build-action-if-i-dont-have-privileges-to-d)

I'm willing to move/copy/rsync files from jenkins workspace to

> /var/www/app

with rights setted to

> apache:**apache**

**I've added jenkins to group** **apache**, but the instance of jenkins cannot copy files to /var/www/app.

I've also tried with setting privileges of /var/www/app to apache:jenkins but still, Jenkins keep spitting out error: Permission denied or Operation not permitted

PS: Forgot to add OS is centOS ;)

EDIT 1: 
This is log from jenkins script runnig:

> [workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1379987233097some_more_numbers.sh
>   + sh /path_to_sh_script/script.sh sending incremental file list
>
> application/
>
> rsync: failed to set permissions on "/var/www/app/application":
>   Operation not permitted (1)

And this is the script itself :)

> #!/bin/bash
>
> rsync -avzh /path/to/jenkins/jobs/app/workspace/default/application /var/www/app ;
>
> rsync -avzh /path/to/jenkins/jobs/app/workspace/default/library
>   /var/www/app ;
>
> rsync -avzh
>   /path/to/jenkins/jobs/app/workspace/default/public /var/www/app ;

Comment: Have you checked that directories are group writeable?

Comment: @Karlson Thanks for Your idea. But still... those are 0774. And this just doesn't work. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long and fruitful discussion in the comments, and following [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/299939/rsync-setting-file-permissions-problem) the user managed to solve the problem adding

`--no-perms --omit-dir-times`

to the `rsync` options.

*Preliminary attempts to solve the issue:*

I guess if security does not concern you for a short period of time, you can try

```
chmod a+rwx /var/www/app
```

and then try to write to this directory. Note that if there are subdirectories you must do it recursively with:

```
chmod --recursive a+rwx /var/www/app
```

If it's successful, then you can start removing permissions gradually and this will help you pinpoint the problem.

Verify that the user jenkins is already a group member of apache with

```
groups apache
```

Comment: $ groups apache

**apache : apache jenkins**

And i did granted all priviliges to group apache, then after no succes changed it to apache:jeknins and even this didn't help. :(

Comment: If the "others" have rwx can you write even one file on this directory or not? Your username is small case right? E.g. jenkins and not Jenkins?

Comment: Also, if you are using another disk for `/var` or one of the relevant subdirectories, it is mounted as writable, right?

Comment: No :/ 

rsync: failed to set permissions on "/var/www/app": Operation not permitted (1)

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the exact commands you are using? Do you have ssh access to the server?

Comment: I don't think there is another disk involved - it's OVH vps and mount didn't show that /var is mounted elsewhere

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the `/etc/rsyncd.conf`? Maybe the configuration does not allow you to write.

Comment: Check question edit: "EDIT 1" :)

Comment: /etc/rsyncd.conf: No such file or directory

Comment: I think this is the problem: http://superuser.com/questions/299939/rsync-setting-file-permissions-problem If you have ssh access to the server you can also try compressing your local files, sending them over ssh with scp and then ssh on the server and decompress them there.

Comment: Thanks for getting me there :) I've founded the answer.
Add this to Your answer and I will happily accept it:
ADD OPTIONS: --no-perms --omit-dir-times  to RSYNC command

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I wanted to write to /var/www on localhost in Jenkins. On my server /var/www is owned by www-data, so I added jenkins to www-data group and made /var/www group writable but kept getting permission denied error. Simply restarting jenkins service fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Same with me, I've been throwing this one around for three hours now, restarted jenkins... and yep.. solved.   It's the same as if you add yourself to a group while logged in, you have to log-out then back in for it to take effect, it's no different with jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

First add your Linux or apache server to the Jenkin server with SSH with ssh-key exchange . And create an user in linux/apache server with a user as jenkin(unix user). Because if you do ssh for pull/push file jenkin's uses 'jenkin' as standard user.

Add apache user to jenkin group in unix may helpful.

Comment: Really great thanks for Your answer! Hope it will help and i will be able to give You all this reputation points!! All happens at very same server. :)
How to do that on the same server?

Comment: Do You know or not? :) Bounty is expiring! :) And I cannot accept Your answer without checking if it's correct and I kinda don't know how to! :)
Do I have to login via ssh at localhost on user jenkins or apache? Or root-like account? Because both apache and jenkins are "not able to login" accounts.